# Is there a spell for storing items or objects similar to a Find Familiar?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, equipment, planes, content-identification

I remember somewhere I watch a spellcaster bamf an item they had in their hand and make it reappear in their hand at will, explaining it's stored in a small plane that only they can access. But I can't find if it matches any official D&D spell. The game system used was definitely 5e. Is there such a thing?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

#### *Wristpocket*

The spell [*wristpocket*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/wristpocket) does exactly what you describe:

> You flick your wrist, causing one object in your hand to vanish. The object, which only you can be holding and can weigh no more than 5 pounds, is transported to an extradimensional space, where it remains for the duration.

You can then use your action to retrieve the object or put it back in the pocket space. The duration is only one hour, so it isn’t suitable for long term storage.

What you are recalling is the Wizard Caleb Widogast from *Critical Role Campaign 2*, “bamf” is exactly the word they used for dismissing Frumpkin, Caleb’s cat familiar, as well as objects into the *wristpocket* space. The spell is an original design of Matthew Mercer and/or Liam O’Brien, but it was later published in the official D&D sourcebook *Explorer’s Guide to Wildemount* (page 190).

For long term storage, Caleb later invented the spell [*Widogast’s vault of amber*](https://criticalrole.fandom.com/wiki/Widogast%27s_Vault_of_Amber), though this spell has not been published in any official D&D source.

Comment: Holy mac and cheese... I was not expecting so much detail, thank you very much! I was guessing it was from there but the only thing I remembered was the vault so I started searching through the other shows. I was never going to find it XD. Thank you!

Comment: They also used "bamf" in Campaign 1, mostly when teleporting through trees. It seems to originate from the Marvel Comics character Nightcrawler; BAMF is the onomatopoeia used in the comic whenever he teleports.

Comment: @JordiVermeulen They also occasionally use "vamp", any idea about the origin there?

Comment: @ThomasMarkov not sure, I've only heard them use the word "vamping" whenever their character is just spouting nonsense. One meaning of the word is "invent, fabricate".